# GNU find, keep {} as is with -exec

Tags: linux, bash

I've been trying to replace the content of a file with `{}` with a command.
The thing is that I want to do that if the file hasn't been changed since 6am so I'm using this command :

```
sudo find /path/to/file -type f ! -newermt '06:00:00' -exec echo "{}" > '/path/to/file' \;
```

The problem is that with the find command the `{}` are replaced with the path of the file that has been found, and I tried using quotes, or doube quotes or anti-slash but I can't get it to work properly...

Does anybody know the correct syntax ?

Thanks

Comment: You know `> '/path/to/file'` redirects find's output, not echo's, right?

Comment: I suggest you to update your question title with "GNU find, keep {} as is with -exec", this way the question will be more easily found on SO  for others. (Surprisingly, it seems that question was never asked until now...)

Comment: @oguzismail Actually, no I didn't know, do you know how I can make it redirect echo's output ?

Comment: See my comment on Socowi's answer. If you still have problems, edit your question accordingly and let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the GNU coreutils `echo` command, you can use character encoding like that :

```sh
sudo find /path/to/file -type f ! -newermt '06:00:00' \
        -exec echo -e "\\0173\\0175" > '/path/to/file' \;
```

Explanation: We use the octal ascii code for the curly braces, `\\0173` for '{' and `\\0175` for '}' with the flag `-e` for the `echo` command. That way, `find` will not see a pattern to put the found filenames, and the `echo` command will output the curly braces ('{}').

Comment: Why double backslash?

Comment: *"`With bash, you can`"* this has nothing to do with bash. `find -exec` does not use bash, but directly calls the binary `echo` from your `$PATH`.

Comment: @oguzismail "\\" works  for both the unquoted args or quoted args.

Comment: @Socowi You're right, the echo command is not a bash-builtin. I should have stated with `GNU coreutils echo`.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

At least in GNU find I couldn't find a way to stop replacing `{}` with the path. Therefore, your question boils down to »*How to print `{}` without using the substring "`{}`"*«.

Here are some examples that can be used inside `find -exec`:

```
printf %s%s\\n { }
```

```
sh -c 'echo {""}'
```

Comment: `sh -c 'echo {\} >/path/to/file'` would do the same and open `/path/to/file` with super user privileges too (mind the `sudo`). I have no idea what OP is doing with that command.